# I restored my MacOS machine from a backup. How to fix errors while trying to read/write non existing files in the /var/folders/ directory?

Tags: spacemacs, backup

I restored my machine from a backup where I hadn't backed up system directories.

Now my restored emacs (spacemacs) insist on trying to read and write from this directory and I keep on getting errors like this:

```
File mode specification error: (file-missing Creating directory with prefix No such file or directory /var/folders/wq/hh0gd3_57pschvmv66g839w40000gq/T/babel-)
[persp-mode] Error: Can not autoresume perspectives -- (file-missing Creating directory with prefix No such file or directory /var/folders/wq/hh0gd3_57pschvmv66g839w40000gq/T/babel-)
```

How can I fix this?

Reinstalling spacemacs (deleting the `~/.emacs.d/` and re-cloning from git) didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had to delete the `~/.spacemacs.env` file which had the directory hardcoded in the `TMPDIR` variable.
This file gets re-created on spacemacs launch with the correct directory.

Comment: Mark your answer as the solution if it fixed your problem.

Comment: Done. It sucks I can't do that right away after answering and because of that I forgot to come back some days later.